# Match multiple pattern from a file and copy matching files in a dir to new dir

Tags: bash, file-copy

How to copy files from dir1 to dir2, matching pattern in a file1?
for example:

file1:

```
T0_1
T0_2
T0_3
```

Dir1:

```
T0_1_xxx_xx
E1_1_xxx_xx
T0_2_xxx_xx
E1_2_xxx_xx
E1_3_xxx_xx
T0_2_xxx_xx
```

I want to `copy T0_1_xxx_xx`, `T0_2_xxx_xx`, `T0_3_xxx_xx` to new dir2. There are 124 names in file1, and 372 files in dir1.

Comment: When you say "I want to copy T0_1_xxx_xx" does that mean that every file that starts with "T0_1_" should be copied? You have to craft the wildcards to match all & only what you want.

Comment: What I mean is, a file contains half names of text files in dir. I want to copy these text files from a dir to new_dir.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the file:

```
while read prefix; do
    cp -- "$prefix"* new_dir_2/
done < file1
```

This will read each line of your file, saving it as `$prefix` and then will copy all files whose name starts with `$prefix` to `new_dir_2`. The `--` after the `cp` is to tell `cp` that there are no more options and this ensures it will also work in the unlikely case where you have a file name starting with a `-`.